# TableView registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier not work

Tags: ios, uitableview

Question is that the contents of cell in tableview are not show!!

List part of codes

**1. In the view controller**

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *mtableview;
```

**2. In viewDidLoad**

```
self.mtableview.delegate = self;

self.mtableview.dataSource = self;

[self.mtableview registerClass:[MyTableViewCell  
class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MytableViewcell" ];
```

**3. In  tableview cellForRowAtIndexPath:**

```
  MyTableViewCell *mcell = [tableView 
     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MytableViewcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

     mcell.mdataname.text = [mdataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

**4.  In MyTableViewCell**

```
 @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mdataname;
```

**5.  I found the mcell not nil , it has been alloc , but mcell.mdataname is nil**

**6.  If I use storyboard to set the MyTableViewCell identifier , and remove the**

```
 [self.mtableview registerClass:[MyTableViewCell  
    class]forCellReuseIdentifier:@"MytableViewcell" ];
```

the contents of cell in tableview are show !!

**7.  So we can't set the identifier of cell  programmatically ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you should have an XIB associated with the custom cell class, and that you should be loading the associated NIB file in the code and registering the NIB (instead of registering the class).

Either that, or your class isn't properly configuring itself in the `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` method (though this option seems less likely as you are using `IBOutlet`).

At the moment, whichever issue you have, `mdataname` is not created / loaded from the archive.

Comment: I found that if init the IBoutlet components in my custom tabelviewCell ( in initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: ) , the contents were show. Thank. your guess is right.