# Why is the table view not displaying anything?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a table view which is set up correctly, but nothing is showing up. The arrays are populated and all the delegates are set up correctly. How do I fix this?
[image]
[image]

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.friendstable.rowHeight = 150.0
    friendstable.allowsSelection = false
    self.friendstable.dataSource = self
    self.friendstable.delegate = self
    self.friendstable.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "friendcell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return titleofsong.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //var cell = friendstable.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "friendcell")

    cell.textLabel?.text = titleofsong[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = artist[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()

    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()


    return cell
}
```

Comment: Does `titleofsong` have any data in it?

Comment: Yes titleofsong and artist do have data in them

Comment: try tableView.reloadData() after you retrieve your contents

Answer (score -1):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.friendstable.rowHeight = 150.0
    friendstable.allowsSelection = false
    self.friendstable.dataSource = self
    self.friendstable.delegate = self
    self.friendstable.registerNib(UINib(nibName:"YOUR_NIB_FILE_NAME", bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier:"friendcell")
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UITableViewCell= tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("friendcell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = titleofsong[indexPath.row]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = artist[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 22)
    cell.textLabel?.textColor =  UIColorFromRGB("4A90E2")
    cell.detailTextLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Lombok", size: 16)
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor =  UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Don't just post code. Please explain what was wrong and how your answer solved the issue.

Comment: in func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) , you need to use a reusable cell. You need to setup a reusable cell either from the storyboard or register one in code. What I have posted above is how to create a custom cell from xib. If you don't want to use xib and do want to register a reusable cell in code, checkout this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23365681/tableview-registerclassforcellreuseidentifier-not-work

Comment: Update your answer with the details instead of posting a comment.